# Set roughike bottombar drawable background

Tags: android, bottombar

I am using roughike bottombar to navigate through fragments in my project, I am trying to set a drawable background to my bottombar but is having difficulty doing so. The example in the official guide https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar only shows how to change the color of the bar. Is there any possible way to do so?

```
    resId = R.drawable.footer_bg_02;
    bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        bottomBar.setBackground(resId);
    }
    bottomBar.setFragmentItems(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragmentContainer,
            new BottomBarFragment(StoreList.newInstance("Content for fragment 1."), R.drawable.ic_01, "fragment 1"),
            new BottomBarFragment(QRscanner.newInstance("Content for fragment 2."), R.drawable.ic_02, "fragment 2"),
            new BottomBarFragment(MyBooking.newInstance("Content for fragment 3."), R.drawable.ic_03, "fragment 3"),
    );

    bottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    getSupportActionBar();
                    //return;
                case 1:
                    //getSupportActionBar().hide();
                case 2:
                    //return;
                case 3:
                    //getSupportActionBar().hide();
                case 4:
                    //return;
                    // Item 1 Selected
            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying to use setBackground but cannot get any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggestion is from [issue](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/205), you can use like this:

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar 
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp"      
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, create a layout and set the background you want to the layout, then place the bottombar inside the layout you created and set the background to transparent color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_color"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/White"
    app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/White"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Or you can use bottomNavigationView (its official) instead of the roughike bottombar.

https://materialdoc.com/components/bottom-navigation/#how-to-style

Answer (score 0):

try this:
add this to parent layout:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

then

```
 <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_activeTabAlpha="1"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/color_white"
        app:bb_behavior="shifting"
        app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="0.6"
        app:bb_inActiveTabColor="#1B5E20"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
        app:bb_titleTextAppearance="@style/style_text"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp" />
```

in your res/xml folder:

`bottombar_tabs.xml` write:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab
        icon="@drawable/drawable1"
        id="@+id/areas_item"
        title="HOME" />
    <tab
        icon="@drawable/drawable2"
        id="@+id/nearby_item"
        title="Nearby" />
    <tab
        icon="@drawable/drawable3"
        id="@+id/my_marker_item"
        title="My marker" />

</tabs>
```

this is the style:

```
<style name="style_text">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

For programetically set items use:

```
  bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);

    bottomBar.setFragmentItems(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragmentContainer,
            new BottomBarFragment(SampleFragment.newInstance("Content for recents."), R.drawable.home, "Recents"),
            new BottomBarFragment(SampleFragment.newInstance("Content for food."), R.drawable.food, "Food"),
            new BottomBarFragment(SampleFragment.newInstance("Content for favorites."), R.drawable.favourite, "Favorites"),
            new BottomBarFragment(SampleFragment.newInstance("Content for locations."), R.drawable.location, "Location")
    );

    // Setting colors for different tabs 
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#3B494C");
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, "#00796B");
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#7B1FA2");
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#FF5252");

    bottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    // Item 1 Selected
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: is there a way to set it programatically ? Since I have not made a bottom bar in my layout file, the bottombar was created directly from my activity

Comment: @JerryKo see the edit..actuall y i don't find any method to change drawable...you can change the color only

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
BottomBar bBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
bBar.setOnTabSelectListener(this);

BottomBarTab tab1 = bBar.getTabAtPosition(0);
tab1.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.WHITE)
BottomBarTab tab2 = bBar.getTabAtPosition(1);
tab2.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.WHITE)

bBar.selectTabAtPosition(0)
```

It's a bit clumsy, but it works.
Just set any color you want and it will update programmatically.

Comment: I have issues like this , How I can change BottomBarTab lable String?